# What is the semantic field of derivatives of 'prae-' + 'emere'?

Tags: etymology

> [3.] [premium (n.)](http://w6ww.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=premium)     c. 1600, "reward given for a specific act,"
>   [2.] from Latin *praemium* "reward, profit derived from booty,"
>   [1.] from *prae-* "before" (see [pre-](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=pre-&allowed_in_frame=0)) + *emere* "to buy," originally "to take" (see [exempt](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=exempt&allowed_in_frame=0) (adj.)). Insurance sense is 1660s, from Italian *premio*.
>   Adjectival sense of "superior in quality" is first attested 1925, originally in reference to butter.
>
> [4.] [pre-emption, n.](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/149931#eid28866465)   < [PRE- prefix](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/149454#eid55940861) + [EMPTION n.](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/61422#eid5541523), after French *préemption* (right to) advance purchase (1569 in Middle French as *preemption*) and its etymon post-classical Latin *praeemption-*, *praeemptio* previous purchase (14th cent. in British and continental sources). Compare classical Latin *praeemere* to buy beforehand
>   (recorded in an 8th-cent. epitome of a 2nd-cent. grammarian).

I can conjecture the semantic shift in the etymology for 4. I can imagine some rich [compulsive hoarder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hoarding)'s excessive buying of some product BEFORE everyone else to anticipate and preclude others from buying the same (this matches the 2016 English definition of 'pre-empt').

5. But how did 3 shift semantically to mean 2? How can the preposition '*prae-*' explain the semantic shift from *emere*'s meaning 'to buy', to '*praemium*'s meaning of 'reward or profit' ?

6. What underlying semantic notions connect 3 and 4?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you can see in your own quotation, *emo* originally meant "take", as it still does in *demo* and *adimo*.

*Praeemo* must have originally meant "to take something before others". If you have the right to take something before others, e.g. from a booty or from the possessions of some other party, then that is likely to be a reward for your valour or other virtues.

Praeemptio is a much later invention, based on the sense of *emo* as "buy". The sense of *prae-* "before others" is the same as that in *praemium*.

Lewis & Short say this:

> praemĭum, ii, n. [prae-emo, what one has got before or better than others] (class.).

Note that they use *has got* in its original sense of "has acquired" here.